# MySQL query table where distinct values relate to multiple rows

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have one person table. A person might have multiple children or dependens, which are also persons. Thus, there is a one to many relationship between the person table.

I want to get all persons that have one or more children. However the query only returns the first matching child for each parent, not all of them. How does the query need to change to return all of them?

```
SELECT parent, child FROM people 
WHERE parent in (select distinct parent from people)
```

I was expecting something more like the form

```
[parent] => Array
{
    [child] => 'Sam'
    [child] => 'Mark'
    ....
}
```

Nothing very complex about the people table, its like the one below:

```
Entry   Parent  Child
1       Josh    Sam
2       Josh    Mark
3       Sue     Tim
4       Sue     Cat
5       Sue     Max
6       Dave    Tia
```

Comment: Show us fields of `person`.

Comment: just info - sql query cannot return tree structure like you want

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `people` table structure would be:

```
id     name     surname    parent_id
------------------------------------
1      John     Smith      NULL
2      Ann      Kowalsky   NULL
3      Matt     Smith      1
4      Jane     Smith      1
5      Rob      Kowalsky   2
```

(where `NULL` means that among this table rows there is no parent registered for such person)
and that you are looking only for parent's direct children, then the query might look like:

```
SELECT 
    parents.id AS parent_id,
    parents.name AS parent_name,
    parents.surname AS parent_surname,
    children.id AS child_id,
    children.name AS child_name,
    children.surname AS child_surname
FROM 
    people AS parents
    LEFT OUTER JOIN people AS children
        ON children.parent_id = parents.id
```

I hope that helps at least slightly.